# Is use of enums justified in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, enums

So I used to maintain configurations as dicts in the past and then stumbled over enums in python.
The following is what I used to do before:

```
CONFIG = {
  "field1": {"field11": "value11", ....},
  "field2": {"field12": "value22", .....},
}
```

This would be a global and would contain some configuration that my application would use.
I then converted the same using enums are follows:

```
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class Config(Enum):
    field1 = {"field11": "value11", .....}
    field2 = {"field22": "value22", .....}
```

The benefit of using enums was quite hazy at first but when I dug deep, I found out enums are immutable, one can enforce uniqueness and it offers a cleaner way to iterate across its members.

I checked if this was used in any of the python third party or standard libraries. I found out that majority of them were using a class as follows:

```
class Config:
    field1 = {"field11": "value11", .....}
    field2 = {"field22": "value22", .....}
```

So my question is, **is enums a good choice to hold configs which shouldn't be accidentally changed** or its just overkill and one can get away with using a class instead?

Would like to know which one is considered as the best practise.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of using enum in your question is that it allows the writing of symbolic constants in the code, whereas using dictionary you'd have have to check the dictionary for the key, e.g:

```
Config.field1
```

versus

```
Config["field1"]
```

So the difference would be advantage in syntax, but also that enum is inherently immutable unlike dictionary, and also that enum can't be extended unlike class.

Comment: But If i wanted to access the value, I would have to do `config.field1.value` which can be a bit verbose and not reqd. don't you think?

Comment: Yes, but strictly in terms of syntax if `Config.field1` is more frequent than `Config.field1.value`,it would be more sparing and elegant. Also depends on usage you give it. In java, at least, the enum would also be optimized over the dictionary because it's immutable. Syntax isn't the only difference to consider, every time you'd consult the dictionary `Condig[field1]` there would be performance overhead from the lookup.

Comment: If you wan't a sugar coated dot notation, then I think `namedtuples` solves the purpose. The only advantage I can think of using enums for this would be that its `immutable` and also has an option to check for `duplicacy` in configs. The only problem I have is, its not used in many standard libraries which shows this feature is either not a good one or neglected by many devs.

Comment: Depends on the collection you use to bundle the tuples together, in your example it would be an enum having a namedtuple as value. That would near optimal, and offer syntax over frozenset. Your argument against `Config.field1.value`overlooks convenience of enum keeping KV together, plus being symbolic. In terms of libraries enum arrived relatively latter in some API's that might be a factor. Enum is certainly good and serves a distinct role from namedtuple.